# Search for budgeting app / web service handling automated sync and multiple currencies

Tags: android, web-apps, finance

I went trough quite a few budgeting web services / phone apps with the features below and could only found one (PocketSmith), but it suddenly stopped syncing EU banks. It would be great to have any suggestion on a budgeting service with the following features:

- [required] both web platform and mobile app
- [required] automated sync with banks from US and EU, or at least from EU
- [required] handling of multiple currencies (so that all transactions appear with the same base currency, whatever their original currency)
- [required] categories and subcategories, customizable
- [required] import of transaction files with categories (and ideally subcategories) information
- [required] budgeting
- [required] multi-users or at least possibility of several users using the same account at the same time
- [preferred] with an API

Any suggestion would be very welcome,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [toshl finance](https://toshl.com/)? I started to use it recently mainly because of the multiple currency feature, was the only one that I could find that works fine. It's paid (the free version is too limited), some other interesting features:

- 14354 bank & financial service connections worldwide
- Mobile apps and Web app
- Import from files
- Unlimited financial accounts
- Unlimited budgets
- Export data
- Reminders
- Lock mobile app with fingerprint or passcode
- List item
- Planning graphs
- Receipt photos